# "Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated" with authenticated user

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse as my backend and I'm trying to "like" a post that another user posted on the app. I'm querying to get the post, then incrementing the number of likes by 1, then adding the current user's object ID to an array that holds all the ID's of users which liked the post.

```
carLikeQuery.getInBackground(carItem.getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                                        object.increment("likes");
                                        object.addUnique("usersWhoLike", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
                                        object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                                if(e==null) {
                                                    Log.d("SAVE", "Like saved :)");
                                                } else {
                                                    Log.e("SAVE", "Not saved :( :" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
```

The error I'm getting:

```
E/SAVE: Not saved :( :java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated.
```

I saw the source code for the ParseUser from somewhere:

```
void validateSave() {
        if (getObjectId() == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot save a ParseUser until it has been signed up. Call signUp first.");
        }

        if (!isAuthenticated() && isDirty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated.");
        }
    }
```

Doing the same kind of checking in my code reveals that the the currentUser **is AUTHENTICATED and NOT DIRTY.**

What could the issue be? To be honest, I want to say that it was working just fine before today, but obviously I was changing something and made a mistake down the line and I can't find it! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like an ACL issue. Are the Posts set to public write?

Comment: @Manu Yes. I resolved the issue by creating an entirely new Parse application with the same data structure/layout.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by creating an entirely new Parse application with the same data structure/layout. It just plain worked without any code changes.

[You can follow the issue on GitHub here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/404#issuecomment-187676624)